# Calculate discount on cell start with S

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to calculate the price of memory cards that have the item code start with "S" with 5% discount

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWIiZ.png)

Here is my code but it seem doesn't work:

```
Sub mem()
Dim rng As Range
Dim element As Range
Dim discount As Integer
discount = 0
Dim i As Long
        
    For i = 5 To Sheets("Sales Point").Range("F5").End(xlDown).Row
    Set rng = Range("F5:F100")
    For Each element In rng
        If Left(Range("F:F", 1) = "S" Then
        discount = discount + Sheets("Sales Point").Range("F" & i).Offset(0, 4) * 0.05
        End If
    Next
    Next i
    MsgBox (discount)
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error?  Have you tried `discount + (Sheets("Sales Point").Range("F" & i).Offset(0, 4) * 0.05)`  Is it a running total you are trying to get?  Would 5% of SUMIF not be ok?  Also is there a need for the offset, as it's static at 4, just change the column letter?

Comment: Do you require vba code? You can do that with Excel formulas. `=SUMPRODUCT(F4:F8,--(LEFT(B4:B8,1)="S")*0.05)`, or if you are using tables: `=SUMPRODUCT(Table1[Total],--(LEFT(Table1[Item Code],1)="S")*0.05)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the running sum of the discount the below code will do all the job.

```
Sub mem()
Dim rng As Range
Dim element As Range
Dim discount As Single
discount = 0
Set rng = Range("F5:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)

For Each element In rng
    If Left(element, 1) = "S" Then
    discount = discount + element.Offset(0, 4) * 0.05
    End If
Next

MsgBox "Total Discount in Cart is: " & Format(discount, "Currency")
End Sub
```

Comment: Declare `discount` as `Double` because it may have decimal part.

Comment: It is just a matter of precision. In Accounting most of the time everything rounds up to 2 digits.

Comment: @Harun24HR Single has a decimal part, but there is no reason to use it since it will mostly only degrade things. Note that there is also a Currency type in vba that use a fixed point number with 4 decimals.